# LXML XPath expression returns only the first child node, while browser confirms multiple children

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to use the Python `lxml` library to parse a web page. In the Developer view of Firefox the page's tree is clearly shown as:

[image: Example]

However, when I run this query in Python:

```
>>> spellTree.xpath('//span[@id="ctl00_MainContent_DetailedOutput"]/child::node()')
[<Element h1 at 0x445a4b0>]`
```

It sees only the `h1` element as a child of the `span`, not the other `spans` or indeed any of the other nodes after the `h1`, even though the tree clearly shows that they are children.

It does identify that the other spans are present in the document:

```
>>> spellTree.xpath('//span[@class="trait"]//child::node()')
[<Element a at 0x445a570>, 'Acid', <Element a at 0x445a5a0>, 'Attack', <Element a at 0x445a600>, 'Cantrip', <Element a at 0x445a5d0>, 'Evocation']
```

But it does not register that they are children of the `DetailedOutput` span. Is my XPath wrong, or is this a bug or exception?

Edit: Python 3.7.3, lxml 4.5.1.

Comment: Try changing `spellTree.xpath('//span[@id="ctl00_MainContent_DetailedOutput"]/child::node()')` to `spellTree.xpath('//span[@id="ctl00_MainContent_DetailedOutput"]//child::node()')` (note two `//` before `child::node`).

Comment: That shows `h1`, `a`, `span`, and `img` which are the indirect descendents of the initial `h1` (not all shown on the screenshot). But it still doesn't show the later `span`s.

Comment: It's hard to tell without the actual url.

Comment: https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably malformed html.

It looks like `//span[@id="ctl00_MainContent_DetailedOutput"]` is not a child of `//span[@class="trait"]`; instead, they appear like siblings. That's why `//span[@id="ctl00_MainContent_DetailedOutput"]//child::node()` shows only 4 child nodes.

This is probably the reason: there seems to be a stray `</span>` inside the `span[@id="ctl00_MainContent_DetailedOutput"]` tag; that's what probably causes the html parser to think that `span[@id="ctl00_MainContent_DetailedOutput"]` is closed, resulting in the treatment of the next span (`//span[@id="ctl00_MainContent_DetailedOutput"]`) as its sibling instead of its child.

Comment: Looks like it. `spellTree.xpath('//span[@id="ctl00_MainContent_DetailedOutput"]/following-sibling::node()')` worked. Wonder why the mismatch with Firefox?

Comment: @MarkGreen Not clear; it could also be something related to how the lxml html parser handles errors. Unfortunately, lxml, in and of itself, is far from perfect.